# how to vertically align the text in a displayfield in extjs 4.1

Tags: extjs4.1

Consider the following item. When i fill the field with text. The text is vertically aligned to the middle. How do i ensure this is vertically aligned top. To be clear i do not mean "My Label" but the actual field value.

```
                                       {
                                            xtype:'displayfield',
                                            name:'FromAddress',
                                            height:100,
                                            fieldLabel:'My Label'
                                        },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'd be nice if there was a `fieldBodyStyle` config, but `fieldBodyCls` will work here:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .align-top { vertical-align:top; }
</style>

{
    xtype:        "displayfield",
    name:         "FromAddress",
    height:       100,
    fieldLabel:   "My Label",
    fieldBodyCls: "align-top"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

setting [labelAlign](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.form.Labelable-cfg-labelAlign) = 'top' works great too